# Package function returns: "Value error: cannot insert 'column name', already exists"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, package, valueerror

I downloaded and have been trying to run the following package: https://pypi.org/project/ecomplexity/#description

Which is also available on github here: https://github.com/cid-harvard/py-ecomplexity

The readme page has an example of how the code is supposed to work, given here:

```
from ecomplexity import ecomplexity
from ecomplexity import proximity

# Import trade data from CID Atlas
data_url = "https://intl-atlas-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/country_hsproduct2digit_year.csv.zip"
data = pd.read_csv(data_url, compression="zip", low_memory=False)
data = data[['year','location_code','hs_product_code','export_value']]

# Calculate complexity
trade_cols = {'time':'year', 'loc':'location_code', 'prod':'hs_product_code', 'val':'export_value'}
cdata = ecomplexity(data, trade_cols)

# Calculate proximity matrix
prox_df = proximity(data, trade_cols)
```

I added `import pandas as pd` so that the .csv file could be read and added `print(prox_df)` to provide the results of the second function. I expected the second function to produce a matrix of values in which the elements are the minimum conditional probability of any two products coming from any location.
However, when running this example from the readme page, I am presented with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath/project.py", line 16, in <module>
    prox_df = proximity(data, trade_cols)
  File "filepath\venv\lib\site-packages\ecomplexity\proximity.py", line 79, in proximity
    output = output.reset_index()
  File "filepath\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4849, in reset_index
    new_obj.insert(0, name, level_values)
  File "filepath\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3618, in insert
    self._mgr.insert(loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
  File "filepath\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1147, in insert
    raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {item}, already exists")
ValueError: cannot insert prod, already exists
```

What causes this error? How can I prevent this error from occurring so that I can use the 'proximity' function of this package?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with pandas 1.1.0 and it failed with same error message.  I then downgraded to pandas 0.25.0 and it worked.

You should consider contacting library author to upgrade to work with latest versions of pandas

```
pip3 install -Iv pandas==0.25.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, this has been helpful, but I'm now getting a new error: 
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath/project.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ecomplexity import ecomplexity
  File "filepath\ecomplexity\ecomplexity.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ecomplexity import calc_discrete_proximity
ImportError: cannot import name 'calc_discrete_proximity' from partially initialized module 'ecomplexity'
```

Do you think I need to set up a new project and attempt this from scratch?

Comment: @BlackLotus501 yes I definitely recommend a separate virtual env for this as there is version hell going on

Comment: Thanks for the input. Just to confirm, the steps here will be: create a new env, open a new python script, install pandas (version 0.25), install ecomplexity again, run the script above again?

Comment: I just opened up a new environment and installed the exact versions of both pandas and numpy listed here: https://github.com/complexly/py-ecomplexity/blob/master/requirements.txt
But I am still getting the same error message

Comment: double check your versions `print(pd.__version__)`. I'm running in jupyter env so I needed to restart my kernel as well